# Data not displaying on recyclerview after button press

Tags: java, android

My data doesn't add to Recylerview after pressing the add button until I either restart the app or press the back button that's built in the action bar. My activity doesn't close after pressing the button so I usually use the back button on my device. Nothing gets added to my Recyclerview until the app restarts or when I add a new set of data and press the back button from the action bar, then 2 sets of data will be added.

I have also tried to finish the activity right after the button press but then that also doesn't add data into Recyclerview.

I want to know how I can make my activity finish after button press and display data in the Recyclerview or make it so that pressing the back button from my device still makes it display.

**MainActivity Code:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton newTaskBtn;
    myDatabase myDB;
    ArrayList<String> task_id, task_subject, task_description, task_due_date;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerTasks);
        newTaskBtn = findViewById(R.id.floatingBtn);
        newTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        myDB = new myDatabase(MainActivity.this);
        task_id = new ArrayList<>();
        task_subject = new ArrayList<>();
        task_description = new ArrayList<>();
        task_due_date = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataArray();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, task_id, task_subject, task_description, task_due_date);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

    }

    void storeDataArray() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                task_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                task_subject.add(cursor.getString(1));
                task_description.add(cursor.getString(2));
                task_due_date.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Add Data Activity Code:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText subjectEntry, descEntry, dateEntry;
    Button addBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        subjectEntry = findViewById(R.id.subjectEntry);
        descEntry = findViewById(R.id.descEntry);
        dateEntry =  findViewById(R.id.dateEntry);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            myDatabase myDB = new myDatabase(AddActivity.this);
            myDB.addTask(subjectEntry.getText().toString().trim(),
                    descEntry.getText().toString().trim(),
                    Integer.valueOf(dateEntry.getText().toString().trim()));


        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter Code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList task_id, task_subject, task_description, task_due_date;
    private int position;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList task_id, ArrayList task_subject, ArrayList task_description, ArrayList task_due_date){
        this.context = context;
        this.task_id = task_id;
        this.task_description = task_description;
        this.task_subject = task_subject;
        this.task_due_date = task_due_date;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_list, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        this.position = position;

        holder.taskid_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_id.get(position)));
        holder.taskSubject_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_subject.get(position)));
        holder.taskDescription_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_description.get(position)));
        holder.taskDate_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_due_date.get(position)));
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(task_id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("Description", String.valueOf(task_description.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("Subject", String.valueOf(task_subject.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("Due Date", String.valueOf(task_due_date.get(position)));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return task_id.size();
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView taskid_txt, taskSubject_txt, taskDescription_txt, taskDate_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            taskid_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskid_txt);
            taskSubject_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskSubject_txt);
            taskDescription_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskDescription_txt);
            taskDate_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskDate_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        }

    }

    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh recycle view in onResume of MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onResume() {     
    super.onResume();
    storeDataArray();
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work, any other solutions?